# ReportViewer field with #erro of object?

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and now I'm creating a report using `ReportViewer`. To do this I created a DataSet Object to pass a List as DataSource. The problem is that my object has a relationship with other objects nested and when I shown the object the report column display `#Erro`. I'm looking for some solutions but still haven't found any yet.

How could I do this ?

trying

```
public class Conta {

        public virtual long id                      { set; get; }
        public virtual Cliente cliente              { set; get; }
        public virtual String historico             { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtLancamento        { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtVencimento        { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal valorFinal           { set; get; }

        public Conta() {
        }
    }


public class Cliente {
        public virtual int id               { set; get; }
        public virtual string nome          { set; get; }

        public Cliente() {
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return nome;
        }

    }
```

**ReportViewer**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it's very simple. Is only add `[Serializable]` on the class.

I did

```
[Serializable]
public class Conta {

        public virtual long id                      { set; get; }
        public virtual Cliente cliente              { set; get; }
        public virtual String historico             { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtLancamento        { set; get; }
        public virtual DateTime dtVencimento        { set; get; }
        public virtual decimal valorFinal           { set; get; }

        public Conta() {
        }
    }

[Serializable]
public class Cliente {
        public virtual int id               { set; get; }
        public virtual string nome          { set; get; }

        public Cliente() {
        }

        public override string ToString() {
            return nome;
        }

    }
```